# How do I string multiple firestore tasks together?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Thanks to Frank van Puffelen and the link he posted to my previous question, I have modified my code but I am far too experienced with Java to be able to implement this. What I need is to query for restaurants from the RESTAURANTS collection associated with the app user, create queries for meal plans from the MEAL_PLANS collection which contain those restaurant IDs. This is as far as I have gotten:

```
private void getMealplans() {
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Restaurant_Data").whereArrayContains("users", getUser()).get().continueWith(new Continuation<Task<QuerySnapshot>, Task<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<?> then(@NonNull Task<Task<QuerySnapshot>> task) throws Exception {
                        List<Task<QuerySnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<Task<QuerySnapshot>>();
                        for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getResult())
                            tasks.add(firebaseFirestore.collection("Meal_Plans").get());

                        return Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks);
                    }
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Task<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Task<?>> task) {
                        List<QuerySnapshot> lists = (ArrayList<QuerySnapshot>)task.getResult().getResult();
                        for (QuerySnapshot qs : lists)
                            for (DocumentSnapshot ds: qs) {
                                Mealplan mealplan = ds.toObject(Mealplan.class);
                                //add to list including day
                                mealplanArrayList.add(mealplan);
                            }
                        // attach adapter to recyclerview
                    }
                });
    }
```

However, I get a compiler error:

```
error: no suitable method found for continueWith(<anonymous Continuation<Task<QuerySnapshot>,Task<?>>>)
method Task.<TContinuationResult#1>continueWith(Continuation<QuerySnapshot,TContinuationResult#1>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) TContinuationResult#1
(argument mismatch; <anonymous Continuation<Task<QuerySnapshot>,Task<?>>> cannot be converted to Continuation<QuerySnapshot,TContinuationResult#1>))
method Task.<TContinuationResult#2>continueWith(Executor,Continuation<QuerySnapshot,TContinuationResult#2>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) TContinuationResult#2
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
where TContinuationResult#1,TResult,TContinuationResult#2 are type-variables:
TContinuationResult#1 extends Object declared in method <TContinuationResult#1>continueWith(Continuation<TResult,TContinuationResult#1>)
TResult extends Object declared in class Task
TContinuationResult#2 extends Object declared in method <TContinuationResult#2>continueWith(Executor,Continuation<TResult,TContinuationResult#2>)
```

How do I navigate this?

Comment: You might want to go over this three part blog series to learn how Tasks work. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html

Comment: I did, Doug and they are really helpful but I am struggling to implement them. I read the blog three times over. Part 1 and 2 are fine but part 3 and 4 are a real challenge; feels like a couple of levels above my current, rather low level of expertise. I did some further reading, particularly Java documentation and at some point I came back here for help. It also does not help that looking at the stack trace, I am not even sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final answer:

```
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Restaurant_Data").whereArrayContains("users", getUser()).get()
                .continueWithTask((Continuation<QuerySnapshot, Task<List<QuerySnapshot>>>) task -> {
                    List<Task<QuerySnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<Task<QuerySnapshot>>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult()) {
                        tasks.add(firebaseFirestore.collection("Meal_Plans").whereEqualTo("restaurantId", ds.getId()).get());
                        Log.d(TAG, "restaurant Ids collected:"+ds.getId());
                    }
                    return Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks);
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<QuerySnapshot> list = task.getResult();
                        for (QuerySnapshot qs : list) {
                            for (DocumentSnapshot ds : qs) {
                                Mealplan mealplan = ds.toObject(Mealplan.class);
                                //add to list
                                mealplanArrayList.add(mealplan);
                            }
                        }
                        // Do something with your array e.g. put it in a recyclerview
                    }
                });
```

The documentation is helpful as far as guidance goes; it certainly pointed me in the right direction but for new programmers like me, we need examples which are more clearcut and comprehensive. Basically, we need more spoon-feeding until we really grasp the concept.